# How to get user profile picture in twitter integration in android?

Tags: android

Hi,
I am new to android trying to integrate twitter with my application. I need to do get twitter profile name and profile picture once the user is logged in. I am able to get profile name but not the profile picture. How can I get the profile picture?

Comment: I had already given the answer,
find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39632369/2623882)

Answer (score 1):

You can get some information in this way:

```
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
twitterApiClient.getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false, false, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
        String name = userResult.data.name;
        String email = userResult.data.email;
        // ... other infos

        // Get the profile pic
        // _normal (48x48px) | _bigger (73x73px) | _mini (24x24px)  
        String photoUrlNormalSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl;
        String photoUrlBiggerSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_bigger");
        String photoUrlMiniSize     = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_mini");
        String photoUrlOriginalSize = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exc) {
        Log.d("TwitterKit", "Verify Credentials Failure", exc);
    }
});
```

From the official doc:

> You can obtain a user’s most recent profile image from `GET users/show`. Within the user object, you’ll find the `profile_image_url`
>   and `profile_image_url_https` fields. These fields will contain the
>   resized “normal” variant of the user’s uploaded image. This “normal”
>   variant is typically 48x48px.
>
> By modifying the URL, you can retrieve other variant sizings such as
>   “bigger”, “mini”, and “original”.

Answer (score 0):

If you've fetched the [user profile](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/users#profile_image_url), look out for the json entry called 'profile_image_url'. Some documenetation from twitter on this can also be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners). Use this in conjunction with an ImageDownloader to download the image to be used as a bitmap in your project. This is the number one google result of how to download and display an image:

http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private TwitterApp mTwitter;
mTwitter.getUserProfileImage();
```

Returns the profile pic of the Logged in user.

Also u can customize the pic according refer : [Android Twitter getting profile image size issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698531/android-twitter-getting-profile-image-size-issue)