# Android Twitter getting profile image size issue

Tags: android, image, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to get the profile images of my followers for use within a ListView as thumbnails.

These thumbnails are around 125x125, but the standard twitter4j call of User.getProfileImageURL(); returns much smaller size of 48x48 and is also recommended to not be used as the image source.

I've tried creating a ProfileImage object and supplying it as a parameter, User.getProfileImageURL(profile image object.Original),

But this code takes some time to simply retrieve the url, which when loading a list of thumbnails, is inefficient.

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit*
Twitter API v1 has been disabled, so my old answer is no longer valid. Refer to API v1.1, which I believe requires authentication.

<del>If you know the screen name, the [twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/%3ascreen_name) allows for you to fetch the profile image at 4 different resolutions;</del>

```
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=Krylez&size=mini
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=Krylez&size=normal
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=Krylez&size=bigger
 https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=Krylez&size=original
```

<del>The "bigger" image is 73x73, which is going to interpolate in your 125x125 container. If you're not okay with this, you can try to fetch the "original" photo, but this photo could be very large (slow) and it's not necessarily a square.</del>

<del>Whatever method you choose, make sure you're not fetching and/or decoding Bitmaps on the UI thread. The Android API documentation has [excellent guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for the correct way to do this.</del>

<del>Also we can make use of the Twitter4j using:</del>

`mTwitter.getUserProfileImage();`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am already aware of what you have stated. 

My question is, why is simply fetching JUST the URL of the 'original' version of the image a time consuming task? It's just getting a string? 
When I tried to implement this via ProfileImage.Original, it took more than a second to simply return the link. But isn't the link just a url object or string? Thank you for any information

Comment: If you look at the source for twitter4j, the LazyUser implementation of User won't actually fetch data from twitter in the constructor. It defers this until the first method call that actually requires that information and then retains it for future method calls.

Comment: Im confused, could you elaborate further please?

Comment: Essentially, I am iterating through status objects, and just want to get the Original sized images to populate the big thumbnail, but the call i described above in getting this URL, is too expensive and results in my feed displaying a few seconds slower.

Comment: Right. The first time you call getProfileImageURL() on a given User object, a network operation is happening. Either perform this method call once per user before you build the listview, or you can construct the URLs yourself (if you already have the username strings).

Comment: Only if Twitter suddenly changes their API. They'd break a lot of apps if they did, so I wouldn't expect it to happen without a lot of warning to developers first.

Answer (score 4):

From the official doc:

> You can obtain a user’s most recent profile image from `GET users/show`. Within the user object, you’ll find the `profile_image_url`
>   and `profile_image_url_https` fields. These fields will contain the
>   resized “normal” variant of the user’s uploaded image. This “normal”
>   variant is typically 48x48px.
>
> By modifying the URL, you can retrieve other variant sizings such as
>   “bigger”, “mini”, and “original”.

Following the code:

```
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
twitterApiClient.getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false, false, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
        String name = userResult.data.name;
        String email = userResult.data.email;

        // _normal (48x48px) | _bigger (73x73px) | _mini (24x24px)  
        String photoUrlNormalSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl;
        String photoUrlBiggerSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_bigger");
        String photoUrlMiniSize     = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_mini");
        String photoUrlOriginalSize = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exc) {
        Log.d("TwitterKit", "Verify Credentials Failure", exc);
    }
});
```

For further information refer to [Twitter API Documentation | Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners)

To create a **custom size pic**, for example 90x90 you can use the `createScaledBitmap()` method.

```
 private final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 90;
 Bitmap originalPic = null;
 Bitmap resizedPic = null;
 try {
     InputStream in = new java.net.URL(photoUrlOriginalSize).openStream();
     originalPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
     resizedPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalPic, PROFILE_PIC_SIZE, PROFILE_PIC_SIZE, false);
 } catch (Exception exc) {
     Log.e("Error", exc.getMessage());
     exc.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getOriginalProfileImageURL()` for example. This is as large as it gets.
Smaller ones are `getBiggerProfileImageURL()` and `getProfileImageURL()`.

These are the urls you retrieve:

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/NUMBER/c62p-cAD_normal.jpeg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/NUMBER/c62p-cAD_bigger.jpeg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/NUMBER/c62p-cAD.jpeg
```