# How to get profile picture in android using Twitter kit,

Tags: android, image, twitter

I'm trying to implement a simple application that uses Twitter kit. The problem is that i'm not able to get the profile picture.Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the answer.

There is a callback which returns you the `User` object.

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true, true, false).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<User> result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

    }
});
```

On the success branch, you can get the `User` object by calling:

```
User user = userResult.data;
```

And from this object you can get all the information form the user. For the profile image:

```
String profileImage = user.profileImageUrl;
```

Comment: That works weell, thank you.
It's retrieving a very low res version of the profile picture. Were you able to get a better quality one?

Comment: I tried the same way, but neither success, nor failure getting called

Answer (score 17):

From the official doc:

> You can obtain a user’s most recent profile image from `GET users/show`. Within the user object, you’ll find the `profile_image_url`
>   and `profile_image_url_https` fields. These fields will contain the
>   resized “normal” variant of the user’s uploaded image. This “normal”
>   variant is typically 48x48px.
>
> By modifying the URL, you can retrieve other variant sizings such as
>   “bigger”, “mini”, and “original”.

Following the code:

```
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
twitterApiClient.getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false, false, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
        String name = userResult.data.name;
        String email = userResult.data.email;

        // _normal (48x48px) | _bigger (73x73px) | _mini (24x24px)  
        String photoUrlNormalSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl;
        String photoUrlBiggerSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_bigger");
        String photoUrlMiniSize     = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_mini");
        String photoUrlOriginalSize = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exc) {
        Log.d("TwitterKit", "Verify Credentials Failure", exc);
    }
});
```

For further information refer to [Twitter API Documentation | Profile Images and Banners](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners)

Answer (score 15):

As of Nov 2016. This works.
There is a change in the implementation of verify credentials.

```
Call<User> user = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false, false);
           user.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                       @Override
                        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                            String name = userResult.data.name;
                            String email = userResult.data.email;

                            // _normal (48x48px) | _bigger (73x73px) | _mini (24x24px)
                            String photoUrlNormalSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl;
                            String photoUrlBiggerSize   = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_bigger");
                            String photoUrlMiniSize     = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "_mini");
                            String photoUrlOriginalSize = userResult.data.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException exc) {
                            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Verify Credentials Failure", exc);
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 7):

from gradle 2.0.0 and up use following method:

```
    Call<User> userResult=Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true,false);
                    userResult.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<User> result) {
                            User user = userResult.data;
                            String profileImage= user.profileImageUrl;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

                        }
                    });
```